# Unresolved dependencies when trying to add jasperreports to play framework 2.2.0

Tags: playframework, jasper-reports, playframework-2.0, repository, sbt

I want to add jasperreports library to my play framework 2.2.0 app. In my Build.sbt, I have added the following lines:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
Resolver.url("Objectify Play Repository", url("http://schaloner.github.io/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
Resolver.url("Objectify Play Snapshot Repository", url("http://schaloner.github.io/snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.4",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27",
  "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.2-RC3",
  "net.sf.jasperreports" % "jasperreports"  % "5.5.0"
)
play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

But in build time, I get the following error:

```
[info] Resolving com.lowagie#itext;2.1.7.js2 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.lowagie#itext;2.1.7.js2
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/rook/play-2.2.0/repository/local/com.lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Maven2 Local: tried
[warn]   file:/home/rook/.m2/repository/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js2/itext-2.1.7.js2.pom
[warn] ==== sonatype-oss-snapshots: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js2/itext-2.1.7.js2.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js2/itext-2.1.7.js2.pom
[warn] ==== Objectify Play Repository: tried
[warn]   http://schaloner.github.io/releases/com.lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Objectify Play Snapshot Repository: tried
[warn]   http://schaloner.github.io/snapshots/com.lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== com.lowagie#itext;2.1.7.js2: tried
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js2/itext-2.1.7.js2.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.lowagie#itext;2.1.7.js2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

What should I do to solve this problem? I have read that if I add a specific jasperreport repositoryt(namely:  http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2), the problem will be solved, but I don't know how to add 3rd party repositories to Build.sbt file. Any ideas?

Comment: I solved the problem by adding 
"com.lowagie" % "itext" % "2.1.7"
before
"net.sf.jasperreports" % "jasperreports"  % "5.5.0"
line. But I still would like to know if there's any other way to solve this, namely by manipulating the resolvers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to your build.sbt:

```
resolvers += "Jasper" at "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2"
```

Or use the Seq with one more entry.

Comment: Nope. Play just gives this error:
[warn] ==== Jasper: tried

As I said, I have solved the issue by adding the iText library to dependencies. I wanted to know if I could use resolvers to avoid adding dependency.

Comment: A resolver is just way to get to a repository. You need be sure that you're pointing to the right one.

Comment: Also this dependency has a weird classifier which is not good (.js2) for dependency resolution patterns.

Comment: your solution works. I just needed to point it to local jasperreports repo. So I marked your answer as the correct one. Thanks!
resolvers += "Jaspersoft third party artifacts" at "http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/"